# How to stop sending Items to ItemWriter if validation fails for even a single item in a File?

Tags: validation, spring-batch

I have a file with 10 items and commit interval is setted to 10. i am filtering the items in item processor for validation errors.

Say for e.g. if 1 or 2 items doesn't pass the validations and filtered in Item Processor , Item Writer receive remaining 8 items and process it.

Is there any way to filter all the items from not being sent to Item Writer if even single item gets filtered in Item Processor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default Spring Batch behaviour when an `Exception` is thrown during read, process or write is to `FAIL` immediatly the whole step.

That is to say, you can simply throw an `Exception` in your process method to prevent all the items in the `commit-interval` to be sent to the writer.

```
@Override
public O process(I item) {

     if (condition) {
          throw new Exception("Item failed validation");
     }
}
```

Now, as I said, your step will `FAIL`, which may not be your desired behaviour. To prevent this, you could for example declare a custom `Exception` class and use it instead of basic `Exception`. You can then configure `skip logic` on your chunk to let the step finish processing the other items :

```
<batch:chunk commit-interval="10" skip-limit="1000000000">
    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
         <batch:include class="xx.xx.xx.CustomException" />
    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
</batch:chunk>
```

Now if you want the step to complete, but not process the rest of the items, you can for example set a flag right before throwing the `Exception` and check it during process. If it is set to true, return null (skipping said item), if not process normally.

Comment: I think the desired behavior explained would be discard the entire chunk when at least one of the the items is invalid. The proper solution could be implement a CustomItemWriter using the delegate pattern that writes only when all the items pass the validation.